# How to move listview itself on y axis

Tags: android, listview, view

First of all please note, I don't need to scroll List *content*, I want to move *whole* list view.
I have a `ListView`, and I want move whole this view vertically. I can do it by putting list into `LinearLayout` container, and then call `scrollTo(x,y)` on that container. Also, I can move my list horizontally, by passing some values to x parameter when calling `scrollTo(x,y)` directly on my `ListView`. But changing y and calling that method on `ListView` has no effect. Maybe someone could suggest a way to move `ListView` vertically without using extra layouts, margins, invisible headers e t.c.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe a picture (quick sketch/mockup) of what you are trying to accomplish would help illustrate the issue more clearly?

Comment: I want to move listview a little bit down, by y-axis, like a view. Like a button. So, not a content of the list, but listview itself. I can do such thing with linearLayout by calling scrollTo(0,20). Listview has the same method, but such calling do nothing (not action at all).

Comment: So, there are lots of ways to accomplish moving a View on the screen.  Maybe I am just a more visual person, but I was hoping that a picture of what you are trying to accomplish would make the proper solution more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move it on your own (touch) you can put it in a ScrollView (can only host one child),
this will let you move the Listview within the ScrollView container.

or, if you want to animate it you could use

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourListView, "y", yNewPosition).setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME).start();
```

Comment: If you do end up wanting to put your ListView in a ScrollView, beware of the complications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing